# PostgreSQL : JOIN reciprocal value with CASE

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have an exercise in SQL (we're using PostgreSQL) where I have to tell if a person `a` is targetting someone `b` and if `a` is targetted by `b`.

I have the feeling that I misuse something, but I'm not sure if it is `JOIN ON` or the `CASE` or just if it is not the right way to have this information.

table a :

```
id    | bio |    password       | ...
--------------------------------------
Anne  |*txt*| *hashed_password* | ...
Beth  |*txt*| *hashed_password* | ...
...
```

table b :

```
id    | target |
----------------
Anne  | Beth   |
Beth  | Anne   |
Anne  | Cass   |
Cass  | Anne   |
...
```

What I'm expecting :

```
a.id | case |  case
----------------------
Anne |  1   |   1
```

What I actually have :

```
a.id | case |  case
----------------------
Anne |  1   |   0
Anne |  0   |   1
```

My SQL code :

```
SELECT a.id, 
CASE WHEN (b.id='Anne' AND b.target='Beth') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
CASE WHEN (b.id='Beth' AND b.target='Anne') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM a
JOIN b 
ON ((b.id='Anne' AND b.target='Beth') 
AND (b.id='Beth' AND b.target='Anne'))
```

*(I've put hard value for testing purpose obviously)*

What should I change/use/do to get the expected result ?
Thank you in advance.

*PS : Sorry if I'm not clear or if there is any mistake of specific term of just in basic comprehension, I'm new in SQL and not used yet to the forums.*

Comment: Why is an integer column called `b.id` when the id column is a string?

Comment: @GordonLinoff It's a Mistake, the column will be named `case` since I didn't renamed it, I'm editing it rn.

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest method is unpivoting (using a lateral join) and aggregation:

```
select v.id, sum(is_targetting), sum(is_targetted)
from b cross join lateral
     (values (b.id, 1, 0), (b.target, 0, 1)
     ) v(id, is_targetting, is_targetted)
group by v.id;
```

This returns the counts, rather than a 0/1 flag.  For that, you can use `max()` instead.

An alternative method -- which returns everyone even those not in `b` -- use correlated subqueries:

```
select a.*,
       (exists (select 1 from b where b.id = a.id)) as is_targetting,
       (exists (select 1 from b where b.target = a.id)) as is_targetted
from a;
```

This returns a boolean flag -- `true`/`false` -- rather than a `0`/`1` number.

Comment: Okay, I've tried the first method, but my lack of experience in `join lateral` gave weird result.
The second method is far more easier, I didn't knew the `exists` command, and it's doing a perfect job. (Since I really need an int instead of a boolean, I added a `CASE WHEN ... THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`)
Thanks for your fast reply, I'll work on lateral join and aggregation, I guess it's a method I should focus on since you've posted it in first place ;)

Comment: @Sidimoth . . . For the second version, you can just do:  `(exists (select 1 from b where b.id = a.id))::int as is_targetting`.

Comment: Yes indeed ! 
It's greatly increasing the readibility, thanks again.